# ASP.NET Web API authorization mechanism in Public website

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I am relatively new to ASP.NET Web API, and I need your suggestion about the following situation: 
Few months back, I participated in a web project which contained an Angular 5 front end, consuming services from a ASP.NET Web API 2 interface. The database was SQL server,  there were several roles in accessing the data so we used token based authenitication.
Lately I am assigned to develop a web interface which will present a lot of charts and reports and will aggregate data from different data sources. I am thinking to use the same infrastructure and frameworks as in the previous project, however I am note sure about the type of the authorization to use. Most of the views will be able to be accessed publicly through https, however we anticipate having some admin views which will of course require proper authentication. I am not completely sure what would be the best pattern here – combining basic/token authentication for public and admin views respectively, or applying token based and creating a public user to access public resources. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your Case I would like to use API Token Based Authentication for all API, But which API you want  only access you (admin API) use [EnableCors(origins: "http://yoursite.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")] this Above your Admin API and  for public use [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] on your public API.Also don't forget to install -> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and add config.EnableCors(); line into webApiconfig under Register Section.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would seperate Admin and Public, that means creating seperate Actions in your API. So you only have to implement the Authorization for the Admin Actions (I would suggest Token Based Authorization). All the Public stuff you can allow annonymously. I hope this was helpful.